# BIGNUM strange behavior in a calculation loop

Tags: ios, openssl

I'm trying to implement a basic routine to perform some calculation on BIGNUM(s) and I've found a strange behavior. The functions are as follows

```
unsigned char *char_array_as_hex(unsigned char *chr_a, int len)
{
    unsigned char *chr_s = (unsigned char *)malloc(len * 2);
    char buffer[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "%02X", chr_a[i]);
        chr_s[(2 * i) + 0] = buffer[0];
        chr_s[(2 * i) + 1] = buffer[1];
    }

    return chr_s;
}
```

and

```
char *big_number_as_decimal_from_hex_array(unsigned char *chr_a, int len, BN_CTX *bn_ctx)
{
    unsigned char *hex_s = char_array_as_hex(chr_a, len);
    BIGNUM *big_number = BN_CTX_get(bn_ctx);
    BN_hex2bn(&big_number, (char *)hex_s);
    char *big_number_as_decimal = BN_bn2dec(big_number);

    free(hex_s);
    BN_free(big_number);

    return big_number_as_decimal;
}
```

and

```
void test_compute_prime256v1()
{
    BN_CTX *bn_ctx = BN_CTX_new();
    BN_CTX_start(bn_ctx);

    unsigned char seed_a[20] = {
        0xC4,0x9D,0x36,0x08,0x86,0xE7,0x04,0x93,0x6A,0x66,  /* seed */
        0x78,0xE1,0x13,0x9D,0x26,0xB7,0x81,0x9F,0x7E,0x90
    };
    printf("s = %s\n", big_number_as_decimal_from_hex_array(seed_a, 20, bn_ctx));

    unsigned char p_a[32] = {
        0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,  /* p */
        0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
        0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
        0xFF,0xFF
    };
    printf("p = %s\n", big_number_as_decimal_from_hex_array(p_a, 32, bn_ctx));

    BN_CTX_end(bn_ctx);
    BN_CTX_free(bn_ctx);
}
```

then I call "test_compute_prime256v1" in an Objective-C method. If I call it once or multiple times with a reasonable delay between each call it produces correct result however, when I call that function in a loop it produces different incorrect values

```
- (IBAction)btnOK_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        test_compute_prime256v1();
    }   
}
```

and a sample output was

```
i = 1
s = 1122468115042657169822351801880191947498376363664
p = 115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951
i = 2
s = 1122468115042657169822351801880191947498376363664
p = 966134380529368896499052403318808180610643774633026536153469502543482958881555881553276...
i = 3
s = 1122468115042657169822351801880191947498376363664
p = 115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951
```

Note: some numbers are trimmed to fit in. I have followed the suggestion in [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_CTX_start.html).
Am I missing something? Is there any mistake somewhere?
Anyone can help?

Thanks

EDITED:

I made some modification to code but the issue still exists. I changed `big_number_as_decimal_from_hex_array` as follows

```
char *big_number_as_decimal_from_hex_array_ex(unsigned char *chr_a, int len)
{
    BN_CTX *bn_ctx = BN_CTX_new();
    BN_CTX_start(bn_ctx);
    unsigned char *hex_s = char_array_as_hex(chr_a, len);
    BIGNUM *big_number = BN_CTX_get(bn_ctx);
    BN_hex2bn(&big_number, (char *)hex_s);
    char *big_number_as_decimal = BN_bn2dec(big_number);

    free(hex_s);
    BN_free(big_number);
    BN_CTX_end(bn_ctx);
    BN_CTX_free(bn_ctx);

    return big_number_as_decimal;
}
```

and also

```
char *big_number_as_decimal_from_hex_array_ex_2(unsigned char *chr_a, int len)
{
    BN_CTX *bn_ctx = BN_CTX_new();
    unsigned char *hex_s = char_array_as_hex(chr_a, len);
    BIGNUM *big_number = BN_CTX_get(bn_ctx);
    BN_hex2bn(&big_number, (char *)hex_s);
    char *big_number_as_decimal = BN_bn2dec(big_number);

    free(hex_s);
    BN_free(big_number);
    BN_CTX_free(bn_ctx);

    return big_number_as_decimal;
}
```

I modified the `test_compute_prime256v1` as

```
void test_compute_prime256v1_ex()
{
    unsigned char seed_a[20] = {...};
    printf("s = %s\n", big_number_as_decimal_from_hex_array_ex(seed_a, 20));
    unsigned char p_a[32] = {...};
    printf("p = %s\n", big_number_as_decimal_from_hex_array_ex(p_a, 32));
        // or
    unsigned char seed_a[20] = {...};
    printf("s = %s\n", big_number_as_decimal_from_hex_array_ex_2(seed_a, 20));
    unsigned char p_a[32] = {...};
    printf("p = %s\n", big_number_as_decimal_from_hex_array_ex_2(p_a, 32));
}
```

but the code produces the same incorrect result in a looped calculation

Comment: i tested your code under linux gcc 64bits and didn't got any weird result. i didn't used any gui though so code is not called within a gui-driven callback.

Comment: quick guess would be to reset context between s computation and p or to get two bignumbers straigh away since http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_CTX_start.html claims 'All BN_CTX_get() calls must be made before calling any other functions that use the ctx as an argument.'

Comment: I modified the code to reflect your suggestion but the result still the same. It produces incorrect result in a looped calc. I've tested it on an iOS 6.0 simulator (iPhone 5.0) under mac-os-x lion 64bit.

Comment: char_array_as_hex should return a NULL terminated string. ( then alloc len *2 + 1 and set chr_s[len*2]='\0'. ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BN_hex2bn(&big_number, (char *)hex_s); expects a C string as second argument, ie a '\0' terminated one since it has no other way to know the size of your string.

Comment: Thanks, Open SSL documentation is too poor and as a novice I've made such mistake. Again thanks